# How to embedded IceCandidates to SDP?

Tags: android, webrtc, stun, turn

The signalling mechanism which we have implemented requires to send the icecandidates in the sdp itself.
Do you have any idea how to embed icecandidates in sdp? 
Also, if the icecandidates are embedded in sdp then how the PeerConnection will initiate p-2-p connection? 
Or does the PeerConnection can initiate p2p connection just after setting the remote sdp or something else has to be done?

Also, can you suggest something on how we can use webrtc for video communication between 2 devices in the same wifi network (without the use of STUN/TURN)? 
I tried setting the iceservers to null but then the app doesn't works!  
I have collected the generated sdp for both the devices from logs. 
I have the ice candidates generated for both peer. I combined the sdp and icecandidates into a single sdp. With this, I have set the iceservers to RTCConfiguration as NULL. But now the app doesn't works!

What I wanna know is that if we have a SDP embedded with icecandidates, how can we initiate the p2p connection? Is the p2p connection initiated when Remote IceCandidate are set or the RemoteDescription is set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ICE candidates are included in the SDP offer/answer. So just wait until the ICE gathering process is complete and then send the SDP offer/answer.

I'm not sure if you can use WebRTC without a STUN/TURN server, but you can use yours or a public one. It seems that on the local environment, everything works fine without a STUN/TURN server - just pass an empty array to `iceServers`.

And for the last question - it depends. If [TrickleICE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/canTrickleIceCandidates) is implemented (and in Chrome and Firefox is) the connection is initiated when the first good ICE candidate is found. And you can set the description before that. Otherwise, you need to wait until the [ICE gathering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/iceGatheringState) process is complete and then send offer/answer and set it on the other peer as remote description. Then the connection will be initiated.

Comment: What do you think:

1. If I don't use stun/turn server, will the sdp be populated with local icecandidates only? In android, the app crashes if the IceServer is not supplied!<br>
2. if the sdp has only local icecandidates (in the same wifi network), will `PeerConnection` be able to connect the peers?

Comment: 1. I doubt that it will work. You can try to pass as `iceServers` an empty array. But the whole ICE thing is based on this to work.

2. If it's a viable candidate, yes, it will connect.

Comment: so passing an empty 'IceServer: and SDP populate with local IceCandidate should probably work! Lemme give it a try!

Comment: Please let me know if it works. I'll update my answer.

Comment: A stun server is not needed if a connection can be found with host candidates (like on a LAN).

Comment: @AdrianBer In local environment without the STUN/TURN server things works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't fit this in a comment so I'm going to post it as an answer.

We run local WebRTC test fairly often with no STUN/TURN servers configured and it works fine. It will just limit your ability to connect via NAT'd firewalls. Can't promise it will connect in your environment but it shouldn't crash. Have yet to try it with Android so no comment there.

As for disabling Trickle ICE, we've run into a few problems with that (mainly on Chrome). You basically have to wait until you receive a NULL ICE candidate before sending the OFFER or ANSWER. This is how the WebRTC engine tells the application the ICE collection process has completed. When we configure to use the google STUN/TURN servers there is a long delay (> 10 sec) between when the last viable candidate event occurs and the NULL candidate event occurs. I've also seen cases where the NULL candidate event is never received and the call just times out.

Our plan is to add a timer to break out of the ICE collection process after a few seconds when Trickle ICE is disabled. I haven't tried it yet but I see no reason why this wont work and should be much more useable. From my experience, all the candidates are collected within the first second or two.

Comment: that 10 second timeout suggests gathering from some interface which does not have a route to the STUN/TURN servers times out.

Comment: Yeah, any VPN on the machine for instance tends to have that effect. A timeout in combination with some minimum candidate count sounds reasonable.

Comment: In local environment without the STUN/TURN server things works fine!